# EL getType obj.property1.sub_property

Tags: java, jsf-2, el

I want to get the type of the sub property of the Object "obj", which is accessible as

`obj.property1.sub_property`

this code works only for direct property like obj.property

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().
     getELResolver().getType(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(),
     obj, "property1");
```

but how to make this work

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().
     getELResolver().getType(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(),
     obj, "property1.sub_property");
```

or How to get the TYPE of the complete expression `#{obj.property1.sub_property}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this work only if obj.preperty1 is not null unless we have a null pointer exception

```
new ExpressionFactoryImpl().createValueExpression(
     FacesUtils.getFacesContext().getELContext(),
     expr, Object.class).getType(
     FacesUtils.getFacesContext().getELContext())
```

because as kolossus mention it will evaluate the first part, then the second...

Comment: If this answer works for you, you need to add some wording or explanation to it. As it stands, it's not of great quality

Answer (score 0):

That's the way `ELResolver` works. Even under the covers, each member is evaluated separately.

From the the specification:

> The ELResolver concept is the heart of the unified EL...For example, in rendering the component behind the tag `<h:outputText value=#{user.address.street}/>`, the ELResolver is called three times. Once to resolve `user`, again to resolve the `address` property of user and finally,to resolve the `street` property of `address`

Translation:
You need to evaluate `property1` and `subproperty` separately. I'm typing this on a phone so I'll add a code sample later

Comment: Wrong, some times you need to get the Type without the evaluation so the solution that i post is better, thank you any way

Comment: @user3252285 - I haven't stated that one is better than the other; If you read what I have here, I said `ELResolver`. **I'm explaining the behaviour of `ELResolver`**

Comment: but u said "You need to evaluate property1 and subproperty separately", my solution is able to detect a more complexe expression like #{bean.formatValue(obj.value)}

Comment: @user3252285 You need to evaluate each *if you're using ELResolver*. Again, not critiquing your solution

Comment: you r right, internaly, it evaluate each var a part